# Data migration tool [ERROR]: Integrity check failed due to "core_config_data" document does not exist in the destination resource

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2.3, data-migration-tool

I'm starting with a blank M2 data with no extensions installed. Using the data migration tool from `ce 1.9.3.1` to `ce 2.3.4` with the following command

```
php bin/magento migrate:settings --auto vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.9.3.1/config.xml
```

I receive error

```
[2020-04-13 22:14:00][ERROR]: Integrity check failed due to "core_config_data" document does not exist in the destination resource
```

In Mysql.php line 110:

```
  SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'i2120969_db1.db_core_config_data' do
  esn't exist, query was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `db_core_config_data`
```

In Mysql.php line 91:

```
  SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'dataname_db1.db_core_config_data' doesn't exist
```

- The 2.3.4 data has a prefix of db_ indicated in the config.xml 
  `<options>
      <map_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.9.3.1/map.xml</map_file><dest_prefix>db_</dest_prefix>`
- I applied the fix in MC-31156 https://github.com/magento/data-migration-tool/commit/387e04f80dc55da2481015c807c158b63646a68a
  with the same result
  the file `core_config_data` is already in `map.xml` to be ignored

I have been working on this for hours and can't find anyone online who has gotten by this error. If anyone has any suggestions it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When you looked at the tables in phpmyadmin the magento 2 tables, if you open the phpmyadmin and you see tables start name see for ex. `mg_core_config_data`

And chnage the your `config.xml` file :-

```
<dest_prefix /> to <dest_prefix>mg_</dest_prefix>
```

Any query let me know

Thanks.

Comment: The 2.3.4 data has a prefix of db_ indicated in the config.xml                                    
<dest_prefix>db_</dest_prefix>

Comment: Please share your database screen shot

Comment: Can you share me Magento 1 and Magento 2 database screen shots??

Comment: Thank you, here are the screen shots https://ibb.co/QkVtcZw

Comment: Please post your config.xml file

Comment: It seems this might be the issue : I installed M2 using installatron and was not asked about splitting the
data. My Magento 2 install put in 3 databases
1-with a "_db" suffix doesn't contain any tables with the word core
2 -with a "_mg" suffix that contains the core_config_data table
3-with a "_fr" suffix doesn't contain any tables with the word core

Since I'm doing the settings migration do I point to the "_mg" suffix in the config file then change it to the _db suffix data to do the data migration?

Comment: i don't understand your comment Please explain me briefly .. and Please post your config.xml file

Answer (score 0):

The config.xml was pointing to the wrong data. After pointing to the correct db everything migrated